# Programatically Exporting Outlook Global Address Book - Not through Exchange

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016

Looking for a programmatic way (i.e. Outlook COM Object/MAPI etc.) to download the Global Address Book.  I can do it via the Outlook GUI: File > Info > Account Settings > Download Address Book.

Answer (score 1):

Use Powershell from your workstation, I would try something like that

```
$filter = (Get-GlobalAddressList 'Default Global Address List').RecipientFilter

Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $filter | Select-Object Name,PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-CSV c:\GAL.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

or

```
get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited | | get-user | select DisplayName,Phone,WindowsEmailAddress | export-csv c:\GAL-Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks -- your answer would use the Exchange PS module (and will work fine using it). However, I am looking to leverage the Outlook client for downloading the address book.